# ImportError:No module named bin.app in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror

I am currently reading LPTHW by Zed A Shaw and i got stuck in Ex51.

```
from nose.tools import *
from bin.app import app
from tests.tools import assert_response
```

I have already added    `__init__.py`     inside the bin directory and added the `PYTHONPATH` on environment variable
When I am giving command on windows powershell, it's showing the import error.

Can anybody help me with this problem? If you have read the book please comment.

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question but does `bin/app.py` exist? Also what exactly did you do with `PYTHONPATH`?